# How to execute shortcut keys from command line?

Tags: command-line, gnome, xorg, keyboard-shortcuts

I am running Gnome. I would like to execute a shortcut key combination from the command line. For example, type a command that generates the key codes for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) to manufacture keyboard events. See the manual and the examples for how to target a specific window.

```
xdotool key ctrl+alt+Left
```

If this is to trigger a functionality of Gnome or the window manager, there may be a separate command line tool for that. For example [wmctrl](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/) gets and changes window parameters such as titles, position, etc.

Similarly, if this to trigger a functionality of a specific application, there may be a way to do this directly. Of course that entirely depends on the application.

Comment: Thanks that works! The command above should be `xdotool key ctrl+alt+Left` though.